# SAS EG Summary Table percentage

Tags: sas, enterprise-guide

When I use Summary Tables in EG to calculate some percentages the result is always multiplied by 100 (5.2 percent is not displayed as 0.052 but as 5.2). 
Now, if I want to display this as '5.2%' I have to divide the number by 100 and then apply the PERCENT format, or I have to 'put' the number as string and add '%' sign at the end.

Is there a way to get percentages from Summary tables
already divided by 100 (0.052 in example above) or is there a way to get them displayed
as '5.2%'. 
Main goal is to avoid that extra step after the Summary table.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One option is to make your own format.

```
proc format;
picture PCT
low-high='009.9%'(mult=10);
quit;
```

That would take the number 5.2 and display it as 5.2%.